# Cassandra - Understanding Rack Concept on PropertyFileSnitch example

Tags: cassandra

I am working on multi DC deployment and one thing is not clear to me - this is the rack concept interpretation from Cassandra perspective.

I can enforce replication order by defining proper key ranges. Why do I need to specify racks additionally in `cassandra-topology.properties` ?

Lets take as example Cassandra documentation: http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/cluster_architecture/replication

If I have replication factor 3, and my row key is stored on Node 1, than replicas will be stored on Node 2 and 3 - this is obvious when we look on ring structure, so... why do I need to duplicate this information in rack configuration?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rack configuration allows cassandra to optimize replica placement so you have better fault tolerance properties.  If you have all your replicas in rack 1, and that rack goes down, you'll lose the data.  If you tell Cassandra about your rack configuration it will keep replicas on different racks.

Comment: but I can enforce this with ring topology, for example: nodes in ring are in order: Node 1, Node 2, Node 3, Node 4. Now I put in one physical rack (not logical cassandra rack) Node 1 and Node 3, and into second physical rack Node 2 and Node 4 - only this without any additional Cassandra configuration will guarantee that each physical rack has copy of each data set. So..... why do I need to define additional logical cassandra racks?

Comment: @MaciejMiklas I have never heard this and am wondering where you get this information?  Even if this is true, it would be inconvenient to have to manage racks this way as your cluster size grows.  I would think your ops team would balk at it.  There are all sorts of scenarios where I can imagine it breaking down.  Either way, I'd really like to know the source of that information.

Comment: "Additional replicas are placed by walking the ring clockwise until a node in a different rack is found. If no such node exists, additional replicas are placed in different nodes in the same rack" - just consider example from this link, if we define only one rack (in Cassandra confing, not by moving physical machines): Rack-A which contains Rack1 and Rack2, Cassandra would still place replicas  on the same nodes - because it would walk ring clockwise, so basically there is no other option. The point is... that I am missing something here and trying to understand it ;)

Comment: Ok, what you're missing is that it does not in fact guarantee where your replica will get placed without rack definition.  The only guarantee is that if you define your racks, the replicas will go in different ones.  If you don't define racks, there are no guarantees as to which node will get the replicas.  I was pretty sure that's how it worked, and in fact the statement above confirms it.  So if you want rack awareness, you have to define your racks.

Comment: If you want the behavior that you're talking about, you could create your own snitch to do that.  But again, I don't think it's a sustainable strategy in the real world of Cassandra operations.

Comment: that was also my understanding - that racks give you extra guarantee. But when you consider that replicas are being placed in ring clockwise and that you define replication factor pro each DC, than you have the same result.....

Comment: You're presuming all nodes are up all the time and you never add nodes or change ownership. In reality these situations will happen.  The bottom line is it isn't guaranteed unless you make it explicit.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21207/discussion-between-maciej-miklas-and-rs-atl)